# Aggregate data for 2 tables sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 questions which I was unable to answer in an interview, and hence do not have the answer.

2 questions are:

**a. Write a query to get close rate by make and partner name (close rate = sales count / lead count)**

Attempt:

```
select  (totalsales/totalleads) as close_rate
(select count(sale_id) as totalsales from daily_sales group by make_name) S
outer join
(select count(lead_id) as totalleads from daily_leads group by make_name) L
on S.make_name=L.make_name
outer join
(select partner_name from partners) P
on L.partner_id=P.partnerid
```

**b. Write a query to Aggregate data to get daily leads and sales count by make and date**

Attempt:

```
select count(sale_id), count(lead_id)
from daily_leads dl
full outer join
on daily_sales ds
on dl.lead_id=ds.lead_id
group by make_name, date
```

TABLES:

Daily_Leads

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| lead_id     partner_id      date_id     make_name |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|     4           2           2019-01-01  toyota    |
|     6           2           2019-01-01  honda     |
|     8           2           2019-01-02  toyota    |
|     9           70          2019-01-01  honda     |
|     2           70          2019-01-01  ford      |
|     7           1           2019-01-01  bmw       |
|     10          4           2019-01-01  bmw       |
|     25          1           2019-01-02  ford      |
|                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Table Name: daily_sales

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| lead_id partner_id          date_id         make_name   Sale_id |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|     4           2           2019-01-01      toyota          1   |
|     6           2           2019-01-01      honda           2   |
|     8           2           2019-01-02      toyota          3   |
|     9           70          2019-01-02      honda           4   |
|     10          4           2019-01-01      bmw             5   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table name partners

```
+----------------------+
| id      partner_name |
+----------------------+
| 1       True         |
| 2       App          |
| 4       Way          |
| 70      Fbook        |
+----------------------+
```

I am trying outer joins which I know is probably wrong. Can someone please help me out?
I am new to StackOverFlow community, so I might not have a proper approach to asking questions. I am learning. Would be great if someone can answer these questions.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the answer (ignore the first page of comments) to the question at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question 
for suggestions and examples of how you might improve your question and your chances of getting a good answer. You've made a good start but it's missing a few pieces that would make it easier to understand what you need.

Comment: Please provide expected results, and the database and its version that you are using. (Tag your question with the database)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any of them. I was asked the questions in an interview, and was not really given any db preference, or results.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use the query joining two aggregate queries.

For `a.`, the query is below:

```
select
  M.make_name,
  P.partner_name,
  L.totalleads,
  S.totalsales,
  S.totalsales/L.totalleads as close_rate
from
  (select distinct make_name, partner_id from daily_leads
   union select distinct make_name, partner_id from daily_sales) M
  left outer join
  (select make_name, partner_id, count(lead_id) as totalleads
    from daily_leads
    group by make_name, partner_id) L
  on M.make_name=L.make_name and M.partner_id=L.partner_id
  left outer join
  (select make_name, partner_id, count(sale_id) as totalsales
    from daily_sales
    group by make_name, partner_id) S
  on M.make_name=S.make_name and M.partner_id=S.partner_id
  left outer join partners P
  on M.partner_id=P.id;
```

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5MTdQvveM4NrAKfe5WArbb/1)

For `b.`, it's similar to a query that changed `partner_id` to `date_id` of the `a.` query.